# How to define an array type where it must have specific values?

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

I'm trying to define a type for an array where the value must contain specific values in a specific order at the beginning of the array.

```js
type SpecificArray = ('hello'|'goodbye'|string)[]

// Currently
const myArray: SpecificArray = [] // okay
const myArray: SpecificArray = [''] // okay
const myArray: SpecificArray = ['something'] // okay
const myArray: SpecificArray = ['hello'] // okay
const myArray: SpecificArray = ['hello', 'goodbye'] // okay
const myArray: SpecificArray = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'something'] // okay

// Desired
const myArray: SpecificArray = [] // fail
const myArray: SpecificArray = [''] // fail
const myArray: SpecificArray = ['something'] // fail
const myArray: SpecificArray = ['hello'] // fail
const myArray: SpecificArray = ['hello', 'goodbye'] // okay
const myArray: SpecificArray = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'something'] // okay
```

I've tried various options, but none have had the desired effect...

```js
type SpecificArray = ('hello'|'goodbye'|string)[]

/* ---- */

type SpecificArray = ['hello'|'goodbye'|string]

/* ---- */

import type { LiteralUnion } from 'type-fest'
type SpecificArray = LiteralUnion<'hello'|'goodbye', string>[]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is no scalable specific type that requires that a value of a particular subtype of the element type be present somewhere in the array.  You can try using unions of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) but that gets unwieldy quickly and is essentially impossible unless your particular subtypes need to show up early in the array.  If you're okay with a *generic* type that acts as a constraint you can do something of the form `asSpecificArray("hello", "xyz", "goodbye")` and get an error if you're missing the required elements.

Comment: I see you accepted the answer below; could you please [edit] the question to indicate that you *require* the first two elements to be `"hello"` and `"goodbye"` in that order?  The accepted answer would prohibit `["foo", "hello", "goodbye"]` but the wording of your question seems to imply that it should be allowed.

Comment: The accepted answer is close to what I need, I think I'm being a bit picky with my TS. I don't need a specific order, so I opted with: `type SpecificArray = ["hello"|"goodbye", "hello"|"goodbye", ...string[]];`. Appreciate this is not scalable, but I only need 2 items to always be defined.

Comment: You opted for `["hello", "hello", "howdy"]` to be acceptable and for `["xyz", "hello", "goodbye"]` to be unacceptable.  Seems wrong to me, but only you know your requirements.  I'm just asking that you [edit] the question to actually lay out your requirements so that the answer addresses the question as asked

Comment: Okay, I'm going to edit the question to say that you require the specific values to appear in a specific order at the beginning of the array, since that's what you accepted.  For what it's worth, something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvGGrw) would be necessary to begin to actually enforce the "these specific values should appear somewhere in the array" requirement you seem to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the order is fixed in your array, then this works:

```js
type SpecificArray = ["hello", "goodbye", ...string[]];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define your type using a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types):

```js
type SpecificArray = ['hello', 'goodbye', ...string[]];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAypDGBLAZo%20BBATpghiKAvFANoDkAFhADZUD2pANFKQOa20AmARiBI1ADohAZ2CZEAOxbEAujKgAfEjIDcAWABQmgPTaoAEQjDEmCB01UIwKAFsQWXCABcsBCjQO8hZSqi6oyDiIVJp2nvhEZKSqfnqBwaH22F6RpMK0NlbkkizRvv7xIRphyREkFNR0ebEBQUUljt5klDT0TKzs3LzV-rQA1niJ4U0VrfwdnDx87emZwNlSPXr9gxpAA)